# Problem with privileges when creating sequences in procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a problem with the execution of the procedure, exactly with the creation of the sequence. I am getting the error ORA-01031 - "insufficient privileges" even though the operation is being performed by the user "system". Code procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc_1
IS
   l_seq_start_with number := 7;
begin
   begin
      execute immediate 'DROP SEQUENCE MY_SEQ';
   exception
      when others then null;
   end;
   execute immediate
      'CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SEQ START WITH '
         ||to_char(l_seq_start_with)
         ||' INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE';
end;
/
```

Calling:

```
BEGIN
   my_proc_1;
END;
```

The same operation in the anonymous block is performed correctly - a sequence is formed.

Comment: And in addition to the correct diagnosis by @Littlefoot, you should _NOT_ be creating your own objects in the SYSTEM schema ... or any other standard oracle-provided schema.  You should be creating them in the schema associated with your app, or - if the object is for general 'dba' work apart from the app itself, create a 'local dba' user/schema.  As an example, suppose your organization uses some acronym to refer to itself. Say International Widgets Corp. is commonly referenced as 'IWC', then you could create IWCDBA to be the local equivalent of SYSTEM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `SYSTEM` was granted the `DBA` role which allows it to create a sequence (among other things). But, privileges acquired via roles will work in anonymous PL/SQL blocks (and at SQL level, of course), but **will not** work in named stored procedures - which is what you have.

Solution? Grant privilege directly to user (`system` in this case).

Demo:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYSTEM"
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc_1
  2  IS
  3     l_seq_start_with number := 7;
  4  begin
  5     begin
  6        execute immediate 'DROP SEQUENCE MY_SEQ';
  7     exception
  8        when others then null;
  9     end;
 10     execute immediate
 11        'CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SEQ START WITH '
 12           ||to_char(l_seq_start_with)
 13           ||' INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE';
 14  end;
 15  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec my_proc_1;
BEGIN my_proc_1; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.MY_PROC_1", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Failed, as you already know. Grant the privilege explicitly:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> grant create sequence to system;

Grant succeeded.
```

Back to `system`:

```
SQL> connect system
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> exec my_proc_1;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select my_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         7

SQL>
```

Now it works.